# Configuration properties are not loaded in Spring Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application which has some configuration properties. I'm trying to write a test for some of the components and want to load configuration properties from a `test.properties` file. I can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

`test.properties` file (under src/test/resources):

```
vehicleSequence.propagationTreeMaxSize=10000
```

Configuration properties class:

```
package com.acme.foo.vehiclesequence.config;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties.PREFIX)
public class VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties {
    static final String PREFIX = "vehicleSequence";

    @NotNull
    private Integer propagationTreeMaxSize;

    public Integer getPropagationTreeMaxSize() {
        return propagationTreeMaxSize;
    }

    public void setPropagationTreeMaxSize(Integer propagationTreeMaxSize) {
        this.propagationTreeMaxSize = propagationTreeMaxSize;
    }
}
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties.class)
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
public class VehicleSequenceConfigurationPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties vehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties;

    @Test
    public void checkPropagationTreeMaxSize() {
        assertThat(vehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties.getPropagationTreeMaxSize()).isEqualTo(10000);
    }
}
```

The test fails with "Expecting actual not to be null" meaning the property `propagationTreeMaxSize` in the configuration properties class was not set.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Two minutes after posting the question, I've found the answer.

I had to enable configuration properties with     `@EnableConfigurationProperties(VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties.class)`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("/test.properties")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties.class)
public class VehicleSequenceConfigurationPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties vehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties;

    @Test
    public void checkPropagationTreeMaxSize() {
        assertThat(vehicleSequenceConfigurationProperties.getPropagationTreeMaxSize()).isEqualTo(10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we have to use EnableConfigurationProperties annotation? Component annotation should convert the properties into a bean?

Comment: @BahadirTasdemir IDK. I just found out this to work.

Comment: :(  Now it is deprecated... :(

Comment: @slashdottir What is it you are referring to that’s deprecated?

Comment: I changed ```@ConfigurationProperties```, ```@Component``` to ```@ConfigurationPropertiesScan```, ```@ConfigurationProperties```. My test couldn't find configuration properties with ```@ImportAutoConfiguration( classes = { MyProp.class } )```. However, after moving it to ```@EnableConfigurationProperties( { MyProp.class } )```, it worked perfectly. Thank you.